# Unit tests for Citrix APIs call?

Tags: unit-testing, api, citrix

I am trying to use [Citrix](https://developer.citrixonline.com/) GoToWebinar and GoToMeeting APIs those allows us to create webinars and allows user to join it etc.

I am trying to develop it in MVC 3 in test driven environment.

But I am quite confused how can I write tests for the methods of API as they all involve sending some data using POST method and receiving it to your redirect url.

For eg. I have to first send a request to there url with the developer key, they returned me back giving me the response key to my application url or the redirect url if it is different from application url. Then in that url page I will have to access that query string parameter sent by them and then have to make the another call to their server with that response key to get oAuth token in JSON format etc.

So this all involves sending data to their server and receiving it to the application URL or redirect url.

I am not able to figure out how I can simulate all this in my test and can run it successfully.

Also, is there a way to get it running with localhost for just testing?

Can anybody please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have got the answer

I tried using WebRequest class' object to send request and receive response from the server inside my test method only and it worked.
Not sure it will help me to implement the API tests entirely but yes it has sorted out the current issue.